# Shipping, freight forwarding, or international moving company?

Tags: shipping

For a transatlantic move between North America and Europe, what are the pros and cons of the different alternatives for bringing my stuff?  Assume the stuff I want to take fits in 6 moving boxes of 58x35x41 cm³ each with at most 20 kg per box.  Assume also it is no problem if it takes a long time to arrive.

- Shipping with a usual customer-oriented company such as Canada Post, FedEx, TNT.  One 58x35x41 cm³, 20 kg parcel with Canada Post from Canada to UK is CA$169.95, which would add up to CA$ 1019.70 — probably there exist cheaper alternatives.
- Sending it with an international moving company
- Shipping it with a freight forwarder
- Other alternatives?

What would be the most cost effective solution?  What could be some reasons to choose an alternative that is not the cheapest?

Comment: Do you really need all that stuff? For some things, it might be better to sell it and replace it when you arrive.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Employer "considers" to pay for shipping if it doesn't cost "too much", but I think convincing them to pay costs for buying new is more difficult.

Answer (score 3):

With only 120 kg of stuff, you can fly with it all if you choose an airline with a generous baggage allowance. For example, [British Airways](http://www.britishairways.com/en-gb/information/baggage-essentials) allows 2 23 kg checked bags, a 23 kg cabin bag, and a 23 kg personal bag for free on transatlantic flights. Each 23 kg extra bag will cost you CA$170.

Another option, which would add some logistical difficulties depending on where in North America you are leaving from and where in Europe you are trying to get to is to cruise there. For example the Queen Mary 2 has an [unlimited baggage allowance](http://www.jaunted.com/story/2014/6/25/24345/5166/travel/Eastbound+or+Westbound%3A+That+is+the+Transatlantic+Question) and [fares start at £899](http://www.cunard.co.uk/cruise-search/book-a-cruise/cruises/qm/1020-m504-sou1-nyc1/staterooms-and-fares/) double occupancy.

Comment: I'd still need to travel to and from the airport on both sides.  This would effectively dropoff/pickup by a large car on both sides, which would, depending on distance, add significantly to the price.